# Loadosophia Virtual Users not correct?

Tags: jmeter

I am running a load test from JMeter and uploads the results to Loadosophia using the Loadosophia.org Uploader plugin. I use stepping thread groups to achieve a ramp-up period of about 35 seconds during which I add 12 threads. These 12 threads then loop thru the different requests for 10 minutes. If I monitor the test in JMeter while running it I can see in the top right corner that 12/12 threads are active for that period. However, in Loadosophia it says that my average virtual user count is around 6.2 and if I look at the virtual user graph I can see that is going up to 7 then down to 3 then up again etc... I don't get a flat line at 12 virtual users in the graphs in Loadosophia. Can someone explain to me why I see these results in Loadosophia?